# Add a HTML file to a Custom URL Protocols on Regedit

Tags: html, node.js, windows, protocols, regedit

## Hey!

I want to make a custom URL Protocol, so mine would be... I dunno `test-protocol://`.

How would I attach a HTML file to `test-protocol://main`